# Issue with multiple instances of ublox_gps nodes

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I have two ublox GPS modules and I want to connect and record data from both of them simultaneously into a rosbag.
I followed [this](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/ublox/issues/7) suggestion and created a launch file as given below. It creates two different nodes *gps1* and *gps2*. But topics are only published in one of them. What could be the error? I highly appreciate any suggestions.

```
<launch>
 <arg name="output" default="screen" />
  <arg name="respawn" default="true" />
  <arg name="respawn_delay" default="30" />
  <arg name="clear_params" default="true" />

  <node pkg="ublox_gps" type="ublox_gps" name="gps1"
        output="$(arg output)" 
        clear_params="$(arg clear_params)"
        respawn="$(arg respawn)" 
        respawn_delay="$(arg respawn_delay)">
    <rosparam command="load" 
              file="$(find ublox_gps)/config/gps1.yaml" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="ublox_gps" type="ublox_gps" name="gps2"
        output="$(arg output)" 
        clear_params="$(arg clear_params)"
        respawn="$(arg respawn)" 
        respawn_delay="$(arg respawn_delay)">
    <rosparam command="load" 
              file="$(find ublox_gps)/config/gps2.yaml" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Thank you

Edit:

Roslaunch output

```
SUMMARY
========

CLEAR PARAMETERS
 * /gps1/
 * /gps2/

PARAMETERS
 * /gps1/dat/set: False
 * /gps1/device: /dev/ttyACM0
 * /gps1/dr_limit: 0
 * /gps1/dynamic_model: portable
 * /gps1/enable_ppp: False
 * /gps1/fix_mode: auto
 * /gps1/frame_id: gps
 * /gps1/gnss/beidou: False
 * /gps1/gnss/glonass: True
 * /gps1/gnss/gps: True
 * /gps1/gnss/qzss: False
 * /gps1/gnss/sbas: False
 * /gps1/inf/all: True
 * /gps1/nav_rate: 4
 * /gps1/rate: 4
 * /gps1/rtcm/ids: [5, 87, 77, 230]
 * /gps1/rtcm/rates: [1, 1, 1, 10]
 * /gps1/subscribe/aid/all: False
 * /gps1/subscribe/all: True
 * /gps1/uart1/baudrate: 19200
 * /gps1/uart1/in: 1
 * /gps1/uart1/out: 4
 * /gps2/dat/set: False
 * /gps2/device: /dev/ttyACM1
 * /gps2/dr_limit: 0
 * /gps2/dynamic_model: portable
 * /gps2/enable_ppp: False
 * /gps2/fix_mode: auto
 * /gps2/frame_id: gps
 * /gps2/gnss/beidou: False
 * /gps2/gnss/glonass: True
 * /gps2/gnss/gps: True
 * /gps2/gnss/qzss: False
 * /gps2/gnss/sbas: False
 * /gps2/inf/all: True
 * /gps2/nav_rate: 4
 * /gps2/rate: 4
 * /gps2/rtcm/ids: [5, 87, 77, 230]
 * /gps2/rtcm/rates: [1, 1, 1, 10]
 * /gps2/subscribe/aid/all: False
 * /gps2/subscribe/all: True
 * /gps2/uart1/baudrate: 19200
 * /gps2/uart1/in: 1
 * /gps2/uart1/out: 4
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES
  /
    gps1 (ublox_gps/ublox_gps)
    gps2 (ublox_gps/ublox_gps)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [5360]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 2459bdc2-f86a-11e8-b9a4-b0359fa7b741
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [5373]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gps1-2]: started with pid [5392]
process[gps2-3]: started with pid [5393]
[ INFO] [1543999540.325794872]: U-Blox: Opened serial port /dev/ttyACM0
[ INFO] [1543999540.325917297]: U-Blox: Opened serial port /dev/ttyACM1
[DEBUG] [1543999540.326219977]: Configuring UART1 baud rate: 19200, In/Out Protocol: 1 / 4
[DEBUG] [1543999540.326422337]: Configuring UART1 baud rate: 19200, In/Out Protocol: 1 / 4
[DEBUG] [1543999540.328171094]: 2.30 (86283), HW VER: 00080000
[DEBUG] [1543999540.328246885]: 2.01 (75331)
[DEBUG] [1543999540.328287796]: PROTVER 17.00
[DEBUG] [1543999540.328329066]: FIS 0xEF4015 (79189)
[DEBUG] [1543999540.328386815]: MOD NEO-M8T-0
[DEBUG] [1543999540.328463317]: TIM RAW 1.01
[DEBUG] [1543999540.328537323]: GPS;SBAS;GLO;BDS;IMES;QZSS
[ INFO] [1543999540.328615602]: U-Blox Firmware Version: 8
[DEBUG] [1543999540.329056341]: 2.30 (86283), HW VER: 00080000
[DEBUG] [1543999540.329139780]: 2.01 (75331)
[DEBUG] [1543999540.329186089]: PROTVER 17.00
[DEBUG] [1543999540.329237753]: FIS 0xEF4015 (79189)
[DEBUG] [1543999540.329286315]: MOD NEO-M8T-0
[DEBUG] [1543999540.329327041]: TIM RAW 1.01
[DEBUG] [1543999540.329364977]: GPS;SBAS;GLO;BDS;IMES;QZSS
[ INFO] [1543999540.329433662]: U-Blox Firmware Version: 8
[DEBUG] [1543999540.391399502]: Configuring measurement rate to 250 and nav rate to 4
[DEBUG] [1543999540.392052605]: Configuring SBAS: usage 0, max_sbas 0
[DEBUG] [1543999540.392678146]: Disabling PPP
[DEBUG] [1543999540.393197616]: Setting dynamic model to 0
[DEBUG] [1543999540.393761297]: Setting fix mode to 3
[DEBUG] [1543999540.394273739]: Setting DR Limit to 0
[DEBUG] [1543999540.395159373]: Read GNSS config.
[DEBUG] [1543999540.395204376]: Num. tracking channels in hardware: 32
[DEBUG] [1543999540.395245356]: Num. tracking channels to use: 32
[DEBUG] [1543999540.395288746]: U-Blox GNSS configuration is correct. GNSS not re-configured.
[ INFO] [1543999540.395332338]: U-Blox configured successfully.
[DEBUG] [1543999540.395378162]: Subscribing to U-Blox messages
[DEBUG] [1543999540.395530543]: Configuring measurement rate to 250 and nav rate to 4
[DEBUG] [1543999540.396215367]: Configuring SBAS: usage 0, max_sbas 0
[DEBUG] [1543999540.396896163]: Disabling PPP
[DEBUG] [1543999540.397478570]: Setting dynamic model to 0
[DEBUG] [1543999540.398291347]: Setting fix mode to 3
[DEBUG] [1543999540.398992193]: Setting DR Limit to 0
[DEBUG] [1543999540.399972056]: Read GNSS config.
[DEBUG] [1543999540.400041409]: Num. tracking channels in hardware: 32
[DEBUG] [1543999540.400096868]: Num. tracking channels to use: 32
[DEBUG] [1543999540.400148743]: U-Blox GNSS configuration is correct. GNSS not re-configured.
[ INFO] [1543999540.400197079]: U-Blox configured successfully.
[DEBUG] [1543999540.400250121]: Subscribing to U-Blox messages
[DEBUG] [1543999540.448697204]: Configuring INF messages
[DEBUG] [1543999540.456096276]: Configuring INF messages
[ INFO] [1543999541.295832536]: INF: u-blox AG - www.u-blox.com
[ INFO] [1543999541.295943535]: INF: HW UBX-M80xx 00080000 
[ INFO] [1543999541.296179711]: INF: EXT CORE 2.30 (86283) Oct 20 2014 13:51:49
[ INFO] [1543999541.296755588]: INF: ROM BASE 2.01 (75331) Oct 29 2013 13:28:17
[ INFO] [1543999541.296844889]: INF: MOD NEO-M8T-0
[ INFO] [1543999541.296978439]: INF: PROTVER 17.00
[ INFO] [1543999541.297351166]: INF: GNSS OTP:  GPS GLO, SEL:  GPS GLO
[ INFO] [1543999541.297691800]: INF: TIM RAW 1.01
[ INFO] [1543999541.297798813]: INF: ANTSUPERV=AC SD PDoS SR
[ INFO] [1543999541.298059219]: INF: ANTSTATUS=OK
[ INFO] [1543999541.298293001]: INF: FIS 0xEF4015 (79189) found
[ INFO] [1543999541.299720163]: INF: LLC FFFFFFFF-FFFFFFED-FFFFFFFF-FFFFFFAE-FFFFFF69
```

Topics and nodes:

```
Latitude-5480:~$ rosnode list
/gps1
/gps2
/rosout
Latitude-5480:~$ rostopic list
/diagnostics
/gps2/fix
/gps2/fix_velocity
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309956/issue-with-multiple-instances-of-ublox_gps-nodes/) by [abkrishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/38844/abkrishna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-12-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2018-12-05**:
could you share the output of launch file?

**Comment by [abkrishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/38844/abkrishna/) on 2018-12-05**:
Edited the question with asked details.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-05**:
This shouldn't be necessary but do you want to try remapping the fix topic from one of the nodes to a different name. Just to see if that makes any difference.

**Comment by [abkrishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/38844/abkrishna/) on 2018-12-05**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd, I tried,

```
<remap from="/gps1/fix" to="/fix"/>
<remap from="/gps1/fix_velocity" to="/fix_velocity"/>
```

but no change in rostopic list.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-05**:
Rather non-intuitively the topic names need to be the other way around in remap.

```
<remap from="/fix" to="/gps1/fix" />
<remap from="/fix_velocity" to="/pgs1/fix_velocity" />
```

Give this a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was rather an hardware configuration issue. One of the GPS sensor was not getting configures using ROS. Had to manually configure it using u-centre software.

---

Originally posted by [abkrishna](https://answers.ros.org/users/38844/abkrishna/) with karma: 16 on 2018-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-05**:
Glad you got it working